# if statement in sub-method returns text error

Tags: java, android-studio

This is likely quite a simple fix but everywhere i look for answers seems to be a slightly different situation.

The question relates to the if statement I wish to return a text value i.e. "hello" in place of 0.00 after return... this comes up with a notification stating requires double. 
I've previously removed all formatting and the *100 multiplier as i understand this wouldn't work but to no avail.

In essence how do you return a text value with an if statement which is a submethod or why doesn't it work with my code?

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

double taxRate, annualSalary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.gobutton:



            EditText employeename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredname);
            String empname = employeename.getText().toString();


            EditText salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredsalary);
            try {
                (annualSalary) = Double.parseDouble(salary.getText().toString());
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                Toast.makeText(this,"please enter a number only!",Toast. LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            break;
            }

            taxRate=getTaxRate (annualSalary)*100;

            String rateStr = String.format("%.0f",taxRate);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


            TextView textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputname);
            textViewName.setText(empname);

            TextView textViewName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputtax);
            textViewName1.setText(String.format(rateStr)+"%");

            break;


        case R.id.exitbutton:

            //Delay the exit by 1 second at this time

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //finish app
                    finish();
                }
            }, 1000);
            break;

        case R.id.returnbutton:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            break;

    }
}


public double getTaxRate(double annualSalary) {


if (annualSalary < 11000.01 ){
   return 0.00;
}
else
    if (annualSalary <= 42000){
        return 0.20;
    }
else
        return 0.40;


    }

}
```

Comment: please try to format the code. make it more readable

Comment: @Closer Please stop playing with close tags. Give new users a chance to improve the question.

Comment: Applogies. not sure how it appears to you but it's formatted on my screen... how can i change it to suit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first double in

```
public double getTaxRate(double annualSalary)
```

is the return type.  In this case it must be a double.  If you want to return a String you must change it to

```
public String getTaxRate(double annualSalary)
```

Comment: Thanks that has resolved my error... seems so simple but i've been looking at it for ages.   Thanks Nathan